# Generic Return type for collections

Tags: java, generics

Is is possible to have a generic return type such that collection can built with interface as well as implementation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test1> list = ImmutableList.of(new Test1());
    List<ITest> test_return_1 = buildIntRange(list);
    List<Test1> test_return_2 = buildIntRange(list); //error
}

private static <K extends ITest> List<ITest> buildIntRange(List<K> test) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(test);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Use the same signature as `ImmutableList.copyOf`, or just use `ImmutableList.copyOf` directly:

```
static <T> List<T> copyOf(Iterable<? extends T> collection)
```